# Problem with AAB file and AR Foundation in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I am writing about a problem I am having with an augmented reality app.

We are using Unity 2020.3.23f1 and AR Foundation v.4.17 (AR Core and AR Kit also v. 4.17).

The problem is related to the build format: when we export to APK the app works and there is no there are problems with augmented reality. Whereas if we export to AAB to put it on the Google Play Console the app freezes when the the augmented reality features are activated: the camera view is not displayed, the screen goes black and the app freezes preventing the user from being able to move forward, then crashes.

I have read about problems related to AR with the AAB file when the Split Application Binary option is enabled. But this is not our case: this option is not enabled.

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/issues/941

Also I read that someone proposes a solution by deleting some files from the Library folder of the project Unity when we go to build in AAB after changing the target architectures (arm64 and armv7, we enabled both)

https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-il2cpp-build-crashes-while-select-both-arm64-and-armv7-architecture.1113217/#post-7493641

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work either.

This situation is frustrating as the APK works perfectly but we cannot put the app on the Google Store because this I accept now only AAB.

Has anyone experienced something similar? Do you have any solution to propose?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.The issue only occurs when the app is compiled with "Split Binary" option. The issue occurs because the UnitySubsystemsManifest.json file that's required for AR Input Subsystem always exist in the main APK while it's being searched in the obb at runtime, if the app was compiled with split binary mode.

The progress on a fix can be tracked here:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-xr-tracking-is-not-working-when-building-app-bundle-with-split-application-binary-enabled

for a temporary fix, you can just update your unity version to  2021.2.4f1 and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this issue when "split binary" wasn't enabled. In my case, I've narrowed the problem down to the Minify Release option in Project Settings > Player Settings > Publishing Settings > Minify > Release.

We're using this option as it also creates the ReTrace mapping file required by google play to publish an app.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers, apparently the problem was related to the "Minify" checkbox in "Publishing Settings".
By unchecking the "Minify" option the app with AAB format works perfectly and allows uploading to google play store without any problems.